# How to move custom view to different superview after it was displayed by UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, ios6, uikit

This is the original layout: A `UIBarButtonItem` displays a custom view inside a `UIToolbar`:

```
+-- main view --------------+
|                           |
|                           |
| +-- toolbar ------------+ |
| | +-- custom view ----+ | |
| | |                   | | |
| | +-------------------+ | |
| +-----------------------+ |
+---------------------------+
```

Here is how I am doing this:

```
UIBarButtonItem* button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.customView] autorelease];
NSArray* items =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:button];
self.toolbar.items = items;
```

After some user interaction I want to remove the custom view from the toolbar and display it somewhere else, in this example directly as a subview of the main view:

```
+-- main view --------------+
|                           |
| +-- custom view ----+     |
| |                   |     |
| +-------------------+     |
|                           |
| +-- toolbar ------------+ |
| |                       | |
| +-----------------------+ |
+---------------------------+
```

I am trying to do this like so (`self` is a view controller):

```
self.toolbar.items = [NSArray array];
CGRect frame = self.customView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 10;
frame.origin.y = 10;
self.customView.frame = frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.customView];
```

This does not work. For some reason the custom view is not displayed after I move it to its new superview. I must be doing something wrong here, but I don't know what it is. Any hints?

Comment: `self.customView` is declared as `retain`? Also check its frame. If you dont add it to toolbar and instead just do the second code, is it working?

Comment: @ACB Yes, the custom view is retained. In my tests I was able to re-add the custom view to the toolbar (via `UIBarButtonItem`), and it was displayed correctly again. Also yes to the remark about the frame. At first I thought I was displaying the view behind the toolbar or something, but this isn't the case.

Comment: But if it was directly added as subview of `self.view`, was it showing properly with the above code?

Comment: @ACB Yes, if skip adding the custom view to the toolbar and instead add it to `self.view` immediately, everything is fine.

Comment: That's confusing. If you put this line `self.toolbar.items = [NSArray array];` below the `addSubview`, does it make any difference?

Comment: @ACB Tried it but, alas, no difference. If it would help I could put up a copy&pasteable code sample, but right now I need to go to bed, it's 4am here and I can't think straight anymore. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

In case you never solved this, or someone else is having the same problem, I think I found out what the problem is.

I'm using Xamarin iOS with C#, but the problem seems to be the same: After having added a custom UIView to UIBarButtonItem.CustomView, the UIView cannot be reused by adding it to another UIView or UIBarButtonItem.

What I did to solve this issue was set:

```
button.CustomView = null;
button = null;
```

I guess the Objective C equivalent would be something like:

```
button.customView = null;
button = null;
```

Then I was finally able to add my CustomView to another UIView using AddSubview().

It seems that once you've created that UIBarButtonItem with your CustomView, the CustomView is bound to that UIBarButtonItem instance. Therefore its important to keep the UIBarButtonItem instance in a class variable so you don't loose the reference to it.

Anyway, thats how it seems to work in my Xamarin/C# environment. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: FYI: In Objective-C the keyword is `nil`, not `null`. Anyway, just to make sure that I understand correctly: Your statement `button = null` is not intended to deallocate the `UIBarButtonItem` instance? And: What is the iOS version you are working with?